# How to set Additional Data in highcharts series in android?

Tags: java, android, highcharts, android-highcharts

I'm new to the highcharts stocks lib in android.
I want to add additional data, calculated dynamicly on each mouseOver.

I made a screenshoot of the [current](http://prntscr.com/xvp0zo) one and a draw of my [desired](http://prntscr.com/yimo25) goal.

I searched in the [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com) and tryed out some code, but i didnt found how to implement my feature.
I used a [template](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/android/line-time-series) from the official website.

I tryed out to override the onMouseOver method, but it doen't work.
Is there a way how to implement it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @Ramon, You need to use `getFormatter` function from the `HITooltip` class. API: https://api.highcharts.com/android/highcharts/ Example with JS: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vp53mdjt/